# Capture Image through webcam on JSP Page and store image in folder in java

Tags: java, jsp, web, webcam

How do you capture an image through the user's webcam and save it to file in the default image folder as well as into a database? I'm using JSP and Java in my web app.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy with [OpenCV](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadopencv241jar.htm) & [JavaCV](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavacvjar.htm) libraries , and here is the code snippet to capture image from webcam & save to disc.

```
                IplImage img;  // Image format provided with JavaCV APIs
                OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0); // Camera Device ID (0 for built in , 1 for external etc)

                grabber.start();

                img = grabber.grab();

                String imageName="images_name.jpg";

                cvSaveImage(imageName, img);
```

Comment: cvSaveImage(imageName,img) gives Error cannot find this Method.

Comment: @Rajan Maan      import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvSaveImage;

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer...Now i m facing this error on my JSP Page

Comment: The problem is with your jar files. Try to get the correct jar files from google

Comment: i download the javacv.jar and opencv-2.4.1.jar

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this website :

http://osama-oransa.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/accessing-webcam-within-jsp.html

Essentially:

1. Use a Jquery Webcam Plugin: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/%20
2. Use AJAX to send the data to Java.
3. Get the byte[] and save it.